# php reading posted arrays

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

This is probably a simple question but i have tried for hours without getting anything out:

I'm customizing an opensource WordPress Plugin. When I post on my customized PHP file and `var_dump()` the `$_POST` variables I get the following:

```
array(7) { 
    ["hellomail"] => array(3) { 
        ["email"] => array(7) { 
            ["subject"]       => string(4) "asda" 
            ["from_name"]     => string(14) "Myplugin" 
            ["from_email"]    => string(12) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
            ["replyto_name"]  => string(14) "Test" 
            ["replyto_email"] => string(12) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
            ["params"]        => array(1) { 
                ["schedule"] => array(2) { 
                    ["day"] => string(10) "2013/03/21" 
                    ["time"] => string(8) "00:00:00" 
                } 
            } 
            ["email_id"] => string(2) "25" 
        } 
        ["campaign_list"] => array(1) { 
            ["list_id"] => array(1) { 
                [0] => string(1) "4" 
            } 
        } 
        ["campaign"] => array(1) { 
            ["campaign_id"] => string(2) "24" 
        } 
    } 
    ["receiver-preview"] => string(10) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
    ["_wpnonce"]         => string(10) "999938595d" 
    ["_wp_http_referer"] => string(66) "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=testpage&action=editDetails&id=25" 
    ["action"]           => string(8) "savelast" 
    ["roll_redir"]       => string(0) "" 
    ["submit-send"]      => string(6) "Senden" 
}
```

What I need is the `["campaign_id"]` and the `["list_id"]`. I really have no idea how to get these values, is there an easy way to access them?

Comment: `echo $_POST['hellomail']['campaign_list']['list_id'];` and `echo $_POST['hellomail']['campaign']['campaign_id'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

world of php =)

```
echo $_POST["hellomail"]["campaign_list"]["list_id"]; // to get array
echo $_POST["hellomail"]["campaign_list"]["list_id"][0]; // to get first
echo $_POST["hellomail"]["campaign"]["campaign_id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way the array looks:

```
array(7) { 
    ["hellomail"]=> array(3) { 
        ["email"]=> array(7) { 
            ["subject"]=> string(4) "asda" 
            ["from_name"]=> string(14) "Myplugin" 
            ["from_email"]=> string(12) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
            ["replyto_name"]=> string(14) "Test" 
            ["replyto_email"]=> string(12) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
            ["params"]=> array(1) { 
                ["schedule"]=> array(2) { 
                    ["day"]=> string(10) "2013/03/21" 
                    ["time"]=> string(8) "00:00:00" 
                } 
            } 
            ["email_id"]=> string(2) "25" 
        } 
        ["campaign_list"]=> array(1) { 
            ["list_id"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> string(1) "4" 
            } 
        } 
        ["campaign"]=> array(1) { 
            ["campaign_id"]=> string(2) "24" 
        } 
    } 
    ["receiver-preview"]=> string(10) "myplugin@myplugin.com" 
    ["_wpnonce"]=> string(10) "999938595d" 
    ["_wp_http_referer"]=> string(66) "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=testpage&action=editDetails&id=25" 
    ["action"]=> string(8) "savelast" 
    ["roll_redir"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["submit-send"]=> string(6) "Senden" 
}
```

Try the below snippet to get at the particular array elements your looking for.

```
echo $_POST["hellomail"]["campaign_list"]["list_id"][0]."<br/>"
    .$_POST["hellomail"]["campaign"]["campaign_id"];
```